# Logistick G29 steering wheel rpm lights control through python

Tags: python, led, gamepad, logitech, evdev

I have a g29 steering wheel with force feedback.
I want to control force feedback and LED lights on the wheel by python script.
i used [python-evdev library](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#listing-device-capabilities-devices-with-absolute-axes) to control the force-feedback of the wheel. But I am unable to find any support to control the rev-LEDs on the steering wheel through python.

If any of you got it working here, please share some information.